# Слово "амбициозный" - истинное значение

Tags: лексика

Сейчас в русском языке иноязычная лексика встречается сплошь и рядом. К сожалению, все чаще и чаще люди употребляют слова в несвойственном для них значении. Так, многие мои знакомые путают значение слова "амбициозный" , причем все уверяют, что оно обозначает *целеустремленного, бойкого человека, способного на решительные и смелые поступки.* Даже профессор по истории допускает ошибку. Но во всех словарях черным по белому написано, что слово "амбициозный" имеет значение **"высокомерный", "чванливый".**

Так почему же люди так говорят и как говорить правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите, в каких именно словарях русского языка слово "амбициозный" толкуется как "чванливый". Я нигде не смог найти такого толкования.

Answer (score 2):

Как говорит нам "Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка" Чудинова А.Н. (1910), *АМБИЦИЯ
(франц. ambition, от лат. ambitio). 1) сперва означало домогательство места; потом стремление к милостям и повышению в чинах; 2) самолюбие, честолюбие, чувство чести.* 
Первое значение явно намекает на целеустремлённость, правда тщеславную. Возможно, именно поэтому многие люди считают, что амбициозный человек — это такой человек, который имеет цели по повышению в должности и прочему. Второе же значение, которое дают почти все остальные словари, игнорируется. Многие думают, что амбиция — это вообще просто цель, а не то, что есть. Поэтому и допускают такие нелепые ошибки в речи. Всё дело в незнании значений слов.

Comment: @Валентин, укажите, пожалуйста, какие именно "нелепые ошибки" допускают в речи некоторые люди при использовании слова "амбициозный". Я не вижу указания на ошибки в исходном вопросе.